# Google Sheet Update Api : Getting error [Request is missing required authentication credential]

Tags: api, oauth, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am calling Google Sheet Update Request in Postman with following parameters:

Url:https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/**SpreadSheetId**/values/**SheetName**!A1:D5
Request Type : PUT
Headers :  Authorization - **MyAccessToken**
Request Body :

[image]

Getting Response :
 [image]

**Note** : For Updating into Spreadsheet, I follow these steps :

1. Create an application on Google Api Console using this [link](https://console.developers.google.com/) and then move to Credentials section. Click Create Credentials, then OAuth Client ID, Create Application type as Web Application. For now leave the Restrictions Section. Then Create. Now Application is created.
2. Add some project Name in the **OAuth Consent Screen** Tab
3. Now, Authorize the API using this [link](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). In the right corner, open the Settings Icon. Select **Use your own OAuth Credentials** as true. Add the Client Id and Client secret from the Project on Google Api Console. Select the Scope as **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets** under the Google Sheet Api v4 in the dropdown, then Authorize the API.

If Get **redirect_mismatch_uri**. then Copy the redirect URI till the oathPlayground or before the prompt parameter and paste it into the Authorized Redirect URI under the restrictions Section of project in Google Api Console. Then Access Token will be generated,

4. Get Access Token. Copy this access token in the request which I defined earlier.

But Getting error. I am not able to figure out the problem.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: When I read your question, I worried about the situation of Sheet API v4. Can you confirm whether Sheet API v4 has been enabled at [API console](https://console.developers.google.com/) again? If Sheet API v4 is enabled, you can see it at the dashboard. I don't know know whether this will be a solution for you. I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, sheet API 4 is enabled. Actually, I am able to read the data from spreadsheet using API key. But, not able to write the data into spreadsheet using OAuth token as OAuth token is mandatory for writing i think.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it. As an another confirmation, how about the information of access token? You can retrieve it using ``curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=### access token ###'``. The response includes scopes and the expiration time. If the access token is no problem, it is necessary to think about the request method.

Comment: No, I am not able to retrieve this access token info. I am getting error ie 'either access_token, id_token, or token_handle required'. I think, there is a problem while generating the access token. Can you please help in that.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the result. In your case, your access token may be over the expiration time. So I have a next question. Do you have refresh token?

Comment: Yes, I have refresh token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153336/discussion-between-juhi-matta-and-tanaike).

Comment: I posted how to retrieve access token from refresh token and retrieve information of access token. Here, I have to apologize. About the how to retrieve information of access token, that of my comment was wrong. I'm sorry. I added the correct command. Please confirm it. I said that you have already read data using API. So when you have access token, you will be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have a refresh token, you can retrieve access token using refresh token. As a sample, it shows a method of how to retrieve access token using refresh token by curl. The access token retrieved by refresh token has the expiration time. Please confirm it.

You can see the detail infomation here. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

### Curl command :

```
curl -L \
  --data "refresh_token=### refresh token ###" \
  --data "client_id=### client id ###" \
  --data "client_secret=### client secret ###" \
  --data "grant_type=refresh_token" \
  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

#### Result :

```
{
 "access_token": "### access token ###",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Below curl command is for retrieving the information of access token. If the expiration time of access token had been over, the response is `{"error_description": "Invalid Value"}`. If it's not, you can see a following response.

### Retrieve information of access token :

```
curl -L \
 --data "access_token=### access token ###" \
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo
```

#### Result :

```
{
 "issued_to": "#####",
 "audience": "#####",
 "scope": "#####",
 "expires_in": 1234,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

### EDIT1

This sample code is for updating the range of `sheet1!A1:C2` to `[["test1","test2","test3"],["test4","test5","test6"]]`.

#### Sample code :

```
curl -L -X PUT \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"values":[["test1","test2","test3"],["test4","test5","test6"]]}' \
"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheet ID ###/values/sheet1%21a1%3ac2?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED"
```

#### Result :

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "### spreadsheet ID ###",
  "updatedRange": "sheet1!A1:C2",
  "updatedRows": 2,
  "updatedColumns": 3,
  "updatedCells": 6
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I am able to get the access token using your curl request. But I am getting error : 'Request is missing required authentication credential' while updating the google spreadsheet api. As, I am passing this access token in the Authorization Header.

Comment: @Juhi Matta Was only ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`` included in the scope? If it's so, please add ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`` to the scope. From your comments, you have already enabled Sheet API. By these, I think that the preparation for using Sheet API is completed. Please confirm them.

Comment: Yes, I have included https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets in the scope while generating the access token on OAuth-Playground. 
But, Update spreadsheet api is not working. It is showing Unauthenticated error. And I have already added generated access token in the authorization header.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried with the same scope also. But still getting the same error

Comment: @Juhi Matta I updated my answer, just now. Please confirm it. If you have a correct access token, the sample curl code works fine.

Comment: @daydreamer Welcome. Thank you for testing it and replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.