# Google Drive API creates a File instead of a Folder using curl call

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, google-drive-api

I have been able to get the `access_token` and I am also able to hit the `API` calls to Google Drive.

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.GltQBdS3y-QkCbKhO5K5pO19bBPaHh-KXZJw2ftw2tyxqSXEAYo06FQfHPSQmFtuN7XAlzb9k7cQw2ZkyBsKDcpX91_N3LObEw_Zgj8OvpMwCCPNK1UDjT' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"uploadType": "simple", "title": "mb", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}' https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files
```

But, what's created on the Google Drive is a file with my request body as the file content
[image]
[image]

The entire payload using `curl` looks like following

```
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:400a:800::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (2607:f8b0:400a:800::200a) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.googleapis.com
*  start date: Jun 18 08:35:41 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 10 08:16:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.googleapis.com" matched cert's "*.googleapis.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fcc1c006600)
> POST /upload/drive/v3/files HTTP/2
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.GltQBzZdS3y-QkCbO5K5pO19bBPaHh-KXZJw2ftw2tyxqSXEAYo06FQ6QmFtuN7XAlzb9k7cQw2ZkUZkyBscpX91_N3LObEw_Zgj8OvpMwCCPNK1UDjT
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 89
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 200
< x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2UpR0hclmVI75f-2hK49hCe3OpA3dkW7GR5PCgd4DgOOkeL2KSoVQDgC-bThMDzXvqcYTaWU3St1pruugvcpst9yaslA
< vary: Origin
< vary: X-Origin
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< date: Thu, 25 Jul 2019 15:23:02 GMT
< content-length: 124
< server: UploadServer
< alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
<
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1MZ4s2ikDqTU5tu-5LDuyMx84TwHgw7",
 "name": "Untitled",
 "mimeType": "application/json"
}
* Connection #0 to host www.googleapis.com left intact
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to create new folder in your Google Drive using a curl command.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

  - Your access token can be used for the POST method.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- When new folder is created, you can use `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files` as the endpoint.
- When Drive API v3 is used, the folder name can be set by the property of `name`.

When above modification is reflected to your curl command, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ### your access token ###' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"name": "mb", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}' \
  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is great help! THANK YOU @Tanaike. The 2 incorrect pieces were - 1. use of the endpoint (I don't know which one to choose over the other) and 2. use of `name` instead of `title` in the payload. When I fixed them, it started to work!

Comment: Unrelated question, do you happen to know how to refresh the `acess_token` when they expire?

Comment: @daydreamer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And about refreshing access token, when you have the refresh token, you can refresh the access token. But at that time, the string of access token is changed, please be careful this. About how to refresh the access token using the refresh token, this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991141/7108653

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

why you have google folder mime type?

"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}'

example for Upload and convert from Excel to Spreadsheet
curl -X POST -sSL \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer [Your access token]" \
        -F "metadata={ \
                     name : '[File name on Google Drive]', \
                     mimeType : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' \
                     };type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
        -F "file=@[Your Excel file];type=application/vnd.ms-excel" \
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"